# Execute code when ForEach finish - swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I want to know if there is a method that executes a given code on the event forEach funtion finish (like OnAppear or similar methods provided by apple) and in case no method is available, how can i executed code when ForEach finish.

I have the following code:

```
ScrollView {
    ScrollViewReader { value in
        VStack  {
            let tweets = getFilteredTweets()
            ForEach((0..<tweets.count), id: \.self) { index in
                NavigationLink(destination: TweetWebView(
                    tweetId: tweets[index].id,
                    accountId: self.viewModel.viewState.selectedAccounts.first(where: {
                        $0.screenName == tweets[index].screenName
                    })?.screenName?.lowercased()
                )) {
                    VStack {
                        TweetView(
                            style: .withNoImage,
                            withHeight: true,
                            account: self.viewModel.viewState.selectedAccounts.first(where: {
                                $0.screenName == tweets[index].screenName
                            }),
                            tweet: tweets[index]
                        )
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                viewModel.triggerEvent(.setTweetSelectedIndex(index: index))
                            }
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            }
            .onAppear {
                value.scrollTo(viewModel.viewState.tweetSelectedIndex ?? 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code I want to execute in the event ForEach finish:

```
value.scrollTo(viewModel.viewState.tweetSelectedIndex ?? 0)
```

Comment: To answer your question, there is not. However, this needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but you may have some luck with a `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:)` around your `scrollTo`.  You didn't say what was actually happening, but I suspect your `scrollTo` isn't scrolling like you expected. I think you have an XY problem here. You want to do X, and you think Y is the solution. You can't make Y work, so you post about Y, when you really want to solve X. Y is the running the code once a `ForEach` completes.

Comment: Last is subjective. The for each will not necessarily load all objects at once. There are many factors that will affect how many items are preloaded. Something to consider would be to reverse the array. Giving you the most current at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForEach` doesn't have any appearance of its own. It represents a collection of views, and it is up to the container of the `ForEach` to decide how to show that collection. So what does `onAppear` even mean when attached to `ForEach`? Does it flow down to each view in the collection? It's better to avoid relying on the behavior of such a weird combination.

Attach the `onAppear` to the containing `VStack` instead.

The `scrollTo` method takes the `id` you give it (in this case, `viewModel.viewState.tweetSelectedIndex ?? 0`) and tries to find a view that has a `id` modifier with the same identifier. But you haven't put the `id` modifier on any of the views in your `ScrollView`. You need to use the `id` modifier:

```swift
ScrollView {
    ScrollViewReader { value in
        VStack  {
            let tweets = getFilteredTweets()
            ForEach(0 ..< tweets.count, id: \.self) { index in
                NavigationLink(destination: TweetWebView(
                    tweetId: tweets[index].id,
                    accountId: self.viewModel.viewState.selectedAccounts.first(where: {
                        $0.screenName == tweets[index].screenName
                    })?.screenName?.lowercased()
                )) {
                    // blah blah blah
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                .id(index)
// ADD THIS     ^^^^^^^^^^
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
//      ^^^^^^^^^    MOVE THIS ONTO THE VSTACK
            value.scrollTo(viewModel.viewState.tweetSelectedIndex ?? 0)
        }
    }
}
```